# Play Framework super Class

Tags: jpa, model, playframework

i want to create two table using a abstract super class

i have 3 user's -> Full Time User, part-time user, they have almost the same data

I create the models but the table User is not created :( 
how do i do?
thanks in advance

Model Full time User

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{


     public String name;
     public Date start;
     public Date end;
     public boolean status;


......

     public Project() {
        super();
          }
}
```

Model Part-time User

```
@Entity
public class partTimeUser extends User {

     public Time startTime ;
     public Time endTime; 
}
```

----------------------------------- 2º REPLY----------------------------------------

Can i do like this?
or is diferent when getting the objects?

Model User

```
@MappedSuperclass 
public class User extends Model{
     public String name;
     public Date start;      
     public Date end;
     public boolean status;   
     ......
     public Project() {  
         super(); 
      } 
}
```

Model Part-time User

```
@Entity
public class partTimeUser extends User {
    public Time startTime ;
    public Time endTime;  } 
}
```

Class Full User

```
@Entity
public class partTimeUser extends User {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In JPA you should add some annotations about the type of inheritence.

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "USER")
@Entity
public class User ...

@Table(name = "PART_TIME_USER")
@Entity
public class PartTimeUser extends User ...
```

P.S. The @Table annotation is not necessary. Nevertheless I prefer to define it. It makes the code and its connection to database objects more readable.

Comment: I think, this will also work. You will end up with two tables (PartTimeUser and FullTimeUser) that uses a lot of the same columns.

Comment: magomi
you way does not work, it does not implement the user class

Comment: yes, did that before you fixed, and doesn't work, it creates the tables, but the part_time_user, does not have inheritance nothing from User. The table part_time_user, just have on fild

Comment: Strange. I use the MappedSuperclass type of inheritance in a project and it works like expected. At least in my environment (JPA/Hibernate).